# Who would be most responsible for realigning my perception so that I can be more grateful?

Tags: practice

Would it be Ganesh?  Who would be more interested in keeping people happy, or who helps us find answers?  Feeling grateful for many of my hardships and want to learn more about these forces.

Comment: In Sanatana Dharma Ganesha is the destroyer of hurdles.  He helps seekers and the general people in their day to day lives to overcome the various difficulties in their endeavours. He is also known as 'Vignaharta' The Defeater of Obstacles' and 'Sankataharana' The Destroyer of Difficulties.  That is the reason we invoke Ganesha first in all our prayers and rituals.

Comment: The Q is somewhat unclear to me

Comment: why be grateful? Everything is due to your own karma. See God in everything and everyone, then you will feel God's love.

Comment: Is that what my gratitude is causing?  God's love?

Comment: Looking for answers into something I know nothing about, ain't sure how to help... during the night, I'm overcome with grief, and in the morning, all my thoughts are about how much life has improved trying to power through one challenge after another.  I want the tears to stop, and the blessings to remain, and am wondering who's trying to get my attention by making life happier.